# How can I efficiently filter and store maximum and minimum x,y pairs from a large list in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, append, out-of-memory

I have a loop function to calculate 2 values of the combinations of one list:

```
xyList = []
for i, j in itertools.combinations(mx, 2):
    x= *some calculation*
    y= *some calculation*
    xyList.append([x,y])
```

However, the combinations of the list are too many, there is always a MemoryError. Therefore, I tried to only keep the unique value:

```
    p=[x,y]
        if not (p in xyList):
            xyList.append(p)
```

But there is still a MemoryError. Now I'm thinking of only keeping the maximum `y` and minimum `y` for each `x`, i.e., the outline of this x, y scattered shape. But I cannot come up with an efficient way to do that. What is the possible solution?

Comment: Why don't you store the extremum value as you compute it? Like storing for each x (if possible), the best minimum encountered so far (same for max)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably make `xyList` a *dictionary* instead. Let's say we call this `xy_limits`. Each value of `xy_limits` can be a list which keeps track of the minimum and maximum as its elements. When you encounter a `y` value that is outside this range, you can replace the correct value. Consider:

```
xy_limits = {}
for i, j in itertools.combinations(...):
    ...
    if x not in xy_limits:
        xy_limits[x] = [y, y]
        continue

    old_limits = xy_limits[x]
    if y < old_limits[0]:
        old_limits[0] = y
    elif y > old_limits[1]:
        old_limits[1] = y
```

Since `old_limits` is a `list` (a mutable type) modifications to that variable (e.g. by assigning one of its elements) will be seen in all occurrences of the list, such as that in the original `xy_limits`

Comment: Indeed I was thinking of using dictionary but didn't come up with a proper structure. Thanks for your suggestion!